# Display result precision upto two decimal places in kdb without rounding off

Tags: kdb

```
x:1.375083
pk[x]
pk:{[x] string[[[0.01*floor 0.5+100*x]* 100]mod 100]}
"38"
```

In my function it is rounding off to 38, but i expect result to be 37.5 instead of 38

Comment: What are you trying to achieve in your function?

Comment: I'm trying to get 1.375083 -> 37.5 as my final result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I’m following, 1.375083 is a ratio that you want to report as a 37.5% increase; and that 2.375083 would be a 137.5% increase.

```
q)1.375083 2.375083-1
0.375083 1.375083
q).1*floor .5+1000*1.375083 2.375083-1
37.5 137.5
q)pk:string .1* floor .5+ 1000* -[;1] @
q)pk 1.375083 2.375083
"37.5"
"137.5"
```

Since `pk` is nothing but a sequence of unaries it can be defined as a composition, avoiding the (tiny) overhead of a lambda.
If you prefer a lambda, it is of course

```
{string .1*floor .5+1000*x-1}
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont really understand what your asking for but you are rounding one dp less than you want in your result - please try and give a bit more detail for what you want your function to do and the conditions it should expect.

You should try and run through each stage of your function and print the output. This will help you understand where you are going wrong.

```
q)x
1.375083
q)1000*x
1375.083
q)floor 0.5+1000*x
1375
q)0.001*floor 0.5+1000*x
1.375
q)100*0.001*floor 0.5+1000*x
137.5
q)(100*0.001*floor 0.5+1000*x) mod 100
37.5
q)pk:{[x] string (100*0.001*floor 0.5+1000*x) mod 100}
q)pk x
"37.5"
```